Is it neccessary to provide @Service annotation over ServiceImpl classes?
package com.foodpay.service.Impl;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class FoodServiceImpl implements FoodService {
}
// I just remove @Service annotation over Impl class but it doesn't work anymore.

Yes, it is necessary to provide the @Service annotation (or any other appropriate stereotype annotation like @Component, @Repository, or @Controller depending on the role of the class) over your implementation classes in Spring. This is because the @Service annotation tells Spring that this class is a service component, and it needs to be managed as a Spring bean.

you know you are supposed to at least try and search the answer for yourself before just asking people on SO... you are getting the downvotes for lack of effort -  check out how to ask

No it's not neccessary you can do it other way by Having another class that provide the implementation bean for the service so for Example you have serviceA.java interface and you have ServiceAImpl.java implementation then you can have another class with name ServiceConfiguration for example that will be like this

@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {


@Bean
public ServiceA serviceA() {
  return new ServiceAImpl();
}

}



This, for instance, is one of the design patterns used in some companies that will not use any spring (or any other 3rd party) import statement on the file with a business-logic-like service implementation.
